# Scheduling issue between sender and receiver

Tags: linux, multithreading, ipc, message-queue, scheduling

I have a process with multiple threads. In which, each thread communicate with each other through message queue[Linux].

Sometimes, the sender is too fast at sending messages that after message queue limit, all the sent messages after queue full, are lost completely.

I always thought context switch will happen on message queue sent to the thread waiting/listening on the Queue.

Is this a scheduling problem? Because, irrespective of number of messages sent, the receiver thread never gets the cpu, till the sender completes sending all the messages, to pop out the message.

[environment] : WindRiver Linux 2.6.xx.xx

```
msgQReceive() //is an API from VxWorks, it is just wrappered to work on linux.
```

It is as simple as that.

Comment: can you show us the part of code where you start your receiver threads ? and how they try to read from the message queues ?

Comment: Bhaskar - I have updated the query. please refer. I cant paste the code, as it is proprietary code.

Comment: With no code to check whats happening - its very difficult to asnwer your question. Most likely reason of "receiver thread never gets the cpu" is that this thread is somehow waiting or blocked by the sender thread/queue conditions.Can you check why  (the receiver never gets the cpu ) ? adding some log statements will help I suppose.